# Android: HTTP POST response - 401

Tags: android, post

I have faced with one problem - returning 401 error msg when you already signed in and trying to get access to another secured pages. The mystic of this problem for me is that I can get access to another secured pages after you are signed in if check it via Firefox RestCLient or via iOS app but cannot get  access via Chrome Advanced Rest Client and Android app. However, content-type and other necessary params are set the same in both web tools and apps. I have tried to set different auth headers with encoded login:pass but it doesn`t help and it doesn`t need because it should work without it, I think(at least FF and iOS app work without this header). What`s gonna be wrong?

Response headers of Chrome:

```
401 Unauthorized

Loading time:
29
Request headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Response headers
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 10:01:02 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9
Set-Cookie: peachy=qg3mjvchjh1oionqlhhv0jrn71; path=/ 
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Length: 96 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Response headers of Firefox:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 202
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 09:51:09 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9
```

That is my peace of Restful code in Android app:

```
public String serverRequest(int action, Bundle params) {
    if (action == 0) {
        if (Const.DEBUG_ENABLED)
            Log.e(TAG, "You did not pass action.");
        return "You did not pass action.";
    }

    try {
        HttpRequestBase request = null;
        HttpPost postRequest = null;
        switch (action) {
            case SIGN_IN:
                request = new HttpPost();
                request.setURI(new URI(SIGNIN_URL));
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

                 postRequest = (HttpPost) request;

                 if (params != null) {
                 UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new
                 UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsToList(params));
                 postRequest.setEntity(formEntity);
                 }
                break;

            case SIGN_OUT:
                request = new HttpPost();
                request.setURI(new URI(SIGNOUT_URL));
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
                break;

            case BANK_CARD_VERIFY:
                request = new HttpPost();
                request.setURI(new URI(BANK_CARD_VERIFY_URL));
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

                postRequest = (HttpPost) request;

                if (params != null) {
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsToList(params));
                    postRequest.setEntity(formEntity);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (request != null) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            if (Const.DEBUG_ENABLED)
                Log.d(TAG, "Executing request: " + actionToString(action) + ": " + urlToString(action));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            StatusLine responseStatus = response.getStatusLine();

            int statusCode = responseStatus != null ? responseStatus.getStatusCode() : 0;
            Log.d(TAG, "Status code: " + statusCode);
            }
            }
```

(sign in and sign out are public, bank_verify is secured page. Android app has the same response headers like chrome). It seems there is something problem with session or something else but I`m not sure exactly.

**EDIT:**
It seems I have found what`s the problem here. In Android app I create a new HttpCLient object due to it all old data is losed. But another question - how to make this HttpCLient reusable?

Comment: if you have found an answer, please post it *as answer* and accept it. For a new question please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found. I reuse httpClient everytime in spite of that to use only one which has all session data everytime. Just implement if statement to check if I have already httpclient object then you it otherwise create a new.